# Java 20 and inheritance problems [SOLVED]

Tags: java, inheritance, dao

I have an object I have described as Message:

```
abstract public class Message 
{
    private int id;
    private String status;
    private String timein;
    private String timeout;
}
```

It has an interface:

```
public interface IMessageDAO
{
    //       SETTERS AND GETTERS    //
    public void setID(int newVar);
    public void setTStatus(String newVar);
    public void setTimeIn(String newVar);

    public abstract Message getByID(int id);
}
```

And is implemented by:

```
public class ImplMessageDAO implements IMessageDAO
{
    //       SETTERS AND GETTERS    //
    public void setID(int newVar)              { m.setID(newVar); }
    public void setTStatus(String newVar)      { m.setTStatus(newVar); }
    public void setTimeIn(String newVar)       { m.setTimeIn(newVar); }
}
```

This class is the base class for a derived class of InBox:

```
public class InBox extends Message
{
    private static int    id;
    private static String st;
    private static String ti;

    public InBox( int    i_id, String i_st, String i_ti, );

    public int    getID()       { return id; }
    public String getSTATUS()   { return st; }
    public String getTIMEIN()   { return ti; }

    public void setID(int i_id)         { id = i_id; }
    public void setSTATUS(String i_st)  { st = i_st; }
    public void setTIMEIN(String i_ti)  { ti = i_ti; }

    @Override    
*   public Message getByID(int id)
    {
        int inttmp = -1;

        rs = null;
        m = null;

        String strtemp = "";

        DML = "";

        //Create Statement
        DML  = "SELECT ID, TStatus, TimeIn, TimeOut, ";
        DML += "FROM Message ";
        DML += "WHERE id = "+ Integer.toString(id);
        try
        {
            rs = db.execQuery(DML);
            m.setID(rs.getInt("ID"));
            m.setTStatus(rs.getString("TStatus"));
            m.setTimeIn(rs.getString("TimeIn"));
            m.setTimeOut(rs.getString("TimeOut"));
        }
        catch ( SQLException | NullPointerException se )
        {
            String msg;
            msg  = "\nERROR InBoxDAO::getByID 130: SQL Error:";
            msg += se.getLocalizedMessage();
            msg += "\nSQL: ";
            msg += DML;
            msg += "\n\n";
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
        return m;
    }
}
```

The problem lies with the derived object methods. NetBeans 18 shows an error:"method does not override or implement a method from a supertype...where clearly there is one.

I know there must be something obvious I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

I expected the derived class to not have these problems. I have searched here and other forums but I am still confused as to what I am doing wrong.

[SOLVED]

Comment: `Message` does not contain a `getByID` method.  Since your `Inbox` inherits from `Message`, there's nothing to override.

Comment: For what it's worth, it doesn't seem like `Inbox` should inherit from `Method`.  Rather, `Inbox` should contain a collection of `Message`.

Comment: `InBox` doesn't implement `IMessageDAO` nor extend `ImplMessageDAO`, so I don't see why it would have the `getById` method. If you just want to add a message with the same name with no relation to that interface, then simple remove the `@Override`, but I don't think this is what you're looking to do.

Comment: Tangential: `getSTATUS` should be named `getStatus` to keep in line w/ Java and JavaBean naming conventions. The names in general should be more obviously meaningful. Don't swallow stack traces; human-readable exceptions are fine but are not a replacement for a stack trace. Declare variables close to their use and keep their scope minimal.

Comment: `ImplMessageDAO` doesn't override `getByID`, so that class shouldn't compile.

Comment: OK I have taken all the above suggestions and changed my object accordingly. It now works with InBox extends Message and implementing Dao<Messge>

Thanks for all the help.